# Spotipy: Printing Track Information

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having trouble printing information from a track on Spotify, using spotipy.

I currently have the following code:

```
import spotipy
import sys
import json

urn = 'spotify:track:450vazRH94IB21mom5FkN9'
sp = spotipy.Spotify()
track_info = sp.track(urn)
artist_name = track_info['album']['artists']
artist_name
```

It outputs:

[{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0YWxKQj2Go9CGHCp77UOyy'},
  'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0YWxKQj2Go9CGHCp77UOyy',
  'id': '0YWxKQj2Go9CGHCp77UOyy',
  'name': 'Fabolous',
  'type': 'artist',
  'uri': 'spotify:artist:0YWxKQj2Go9CGHCp77UOyy'}]

When I try and use artist_name = track_info['album']['artists'] and add ['name] to the end, like so:

```
artist_name = track_info['album']['artists']['name']
```

I get this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I'm not really sure why it says that when it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`track_info['album']['artists']` is a list, you need to get item using index (`list[0]`):

```
artist_name = track_info['album']['artists'][0]['name']
```

It can be multiple artists. In such case use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
artist_names = [artist['name'] for artist in track_info['album']['artists']]
```